# Why is the app crashing when I open a push notification?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to open a specific page when the push notification is opened, but it keeps on crashing. Why is that occurring?

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)
  let text = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]
    let title = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]!!["title"]
    let artist = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]!!["artist"]
    print(text)
    print(title)
    print(artist)

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PlayerController") as! PlayerViewController
    vc.dataModel.artistplay = artist as? String
    vc.dataModel.titleplay = title as? String
    vc.playerartist.text = artist as? String
    vc.playertitle.text = title as? String
    window?.rootViewController = vc

    }
```

These are the variables in the PlayeViewController

```
class PlayerViewController: UIViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var playertitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var playerartist: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var play: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var share: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var love: UIButton!

var dicData : NSDictionary?
var dataModel = DataModelTwo()
var data: NSDictionary?
var shareDataModel: Share?
var buttonState: Int = 0;

var liked = [String]()
```

Below is the DataModelTwo

```
class DataModelTwo : NSObject{
var titleplay: String?
var artistplay: String?
}
```

Comment: May I suggest posting up your output console log to shed some light on what is crashing...

Comment: Does the dictionary contain those objects? Also, set a breakpoint, post the stack trace, etc.. Learn to use the debugger.

Comment: This is the error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` and i set the dictionary to contain those values.

Comment: After this line of `window?.rootViewController = vc` did you present the viewcontroller

Comment: It crashes before it reaches that line

Comment: Probably crashes on `let text = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]` or likewise because the dictionary might not contain those keys and you are dereferencing the second argument.

Comment: No it crashes at the `vc.playertitle.text = title as? String`

Comment: maybe that title is an optional.. why dont you comment it out ?

Comment: I commented it out, and it does not crash

Comment: Does title print out in the console or does it print nil

Comment: It works after I comment it out.